# HTTP is working but HTTPS is not working - Apache 2

Tags: apache, ssl, centos

I've configured my virtual host for both HTTP & HTTPS but my website is not accessible on HTTPS. 
I think that knows when the problem started from. HTTP & HTTPS Both work well until I configured postfix and dovecot. maybe installing OpenSSL is the cause of the problem.

My server: Centos7- Apache/2.4.6

When I open my domain on HTTPS I give the below error on chrome:

```
This site cant be reached 
https://psdtohtml.ir is unreachable
```

Getting below error by `wget`:

```
wget https://psdtohtml.ir
--2019-10-22 13:04:20--  https://psdtohtml.ir/
Resolving psdtohtml.ir (psdtohtml.ir)... 130.185.74.134
Connecting to psdtohtml.ir (psdtohtml.ir)|130.185.74.134|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify psdtohtml.ir's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to psdtohtml.ir insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

My virtual hosts in `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/psdtohtml.ir.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.psdtohtml.ir
    ServerAlias psdtohtml.ir
    DocumentRoot /var/www/psdtohtml.ir/public_html/public
   #Redirect "/" "https://psdtohtml.ir/"
    ErrorLog /var/www/psdtohtml.ir/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/psdtohtml.ir/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.psdtohtml.ir
    ServerAlias psdtohtml.ir
    DocumentRoot /var/www/psdtohtml.ir/public_html/public
    ErrorLog /var/www/psdtohtml.ir/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/psdtohtml.ir/requests.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Idk how can I solve that? I've searched for all the internet about my problem but I've not found any solution.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It is completely unknown what you are actually doing and what exactly "not working" means (timeout, error messages, wrong content ...?). Also, given that it stopped working once you've configured postfix and dovecot it is likely connected to what you did there - only it is unknown what you did there too. This essentially makes it impossible to answer the question, i.e. too broad.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for your comment. I updated my answer. I just configured postfix and dovecot step by step from an online tutorial, https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-an-email-server-on-centos7/, and everything was ok. after 1 day I understood that my website doesn't work properly before that everything was ok.

Comment: The domain is currently unreachable for both port 80 (http) and 443 (https). Port 25 (smtp) is accessible though. Either your web server failed to properly startup (check log files for errors) or you have firewall rules configured which block the access.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sorry, My web server has been down due to my stupid mistake and it's up now.

Comment: Port 80 is now open but port 443 is still unreachable. Check your server config and log files and check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old answer, but after trying to get this to work all day, thought I'd share. I forgot to forward port 443 on my router to the server's local IP. After changing this, the configuration worked. I.e. I had all the configurations jiving, but the missing link was the router port forwarding. Apache24 on windows.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the Listen statements in the conf file?

To have apache bind to port 443, the config needs to contain
`Listen 443`

Comment: The error message, quoted in the question, shows that a connection was made.